# Little Snitch network filter Warning when using TeX Live Utility

Tags: tex-live-utility

Whenever I startup TeX Live Utility to update my TeX files, one or more of the following Warnings appear:

*First Warning*:

---

**TeX Live Utility**

wants to connect to **ctan.kako-dev.de** on TCP port 443 (https)

'''Warning

Suspicious process!

The code signature of the process has a formal error. This probably indicates that somebody is trying to pretend a valid code signature , or that the developer used inappropriate, non-standard tools to create the signature.'''

---

*Second Warning*:

---

**tlu_ipctas**

wants to connect to **ctan.kako-dev.de** on TCP port 443 (https)

'''Warning

Suspicious process "tlu_ipctask"!

The code signature of the process has a formal error. This probably indicates that somebody is trying to pretend a valid code signature, or that the developer used inappropriate, non-standard tools to create the signature.'''

---

If I stop the Little Snitch network filter (or run in Silent Mode) the Warnings do NOT appear.

Little Snitch allows the user to bypass such Warnings, but the tone of the Warnings is disturbing and I wonder if anyone else using Little Snitch has had similar Warnings appear when using TeX Live Utility?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just whitelist this process / port / domain?

Comment: Ask on the texlive mailing list.